# Function floor of BigInteger

Tags: java

I'm looking for a function such as Math.floor(int x) but for a variable of type BigInteger. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: JavaScript is __not__ Java.

Comment: Why would you need a `floor` function for an integer? `floor` rounds down a floating point number.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right

Comment: Because I divide the BigInteger  by two and then I wants to round off using this function

Comment: Dividing two `BigInteger`s will round down automatically.

Comment: oh thanks for help... 
in the case of dividing two numbers of type int it also work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Let's suppose `a` and `b` are `int` variables. In that case `a/b` is an `int`. Test case:

   `int a = 5;
   int b = 2;
   System.out.println(a / b); //expected output is 2`
2. Let's suppose `a` and `b` are integers, but we intend to convert the result of the division into a `float`. The result depends on the way of conversion. Test case:

   `int a = 5;
   int b = 2;
   System.out.println((float)(a / b)); //expected output is 0.0
   System.out.println(((float)a) / b); //expected output is 2.5`
3. Let's suppose `a` and `b` are `BigInteger` variables. `a.divide(b)` will return a `BigInteger` value (so floor is not needed) unless `b` is 0 in which case it will throw an exception. [Source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/biginteger_divide.htm).